# Solspace user - percent of profile complete

Tags: solspace-user

I want to calculate the % of the profile a user has complete is this possible?

Maybe even define the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's geared towards doing the same but with *channel* fields, the [Perfect module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/perfect) could get you started down this path. (It will need to be modified, or you'll need to use a module such as [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) or [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) to connect your member with channel entries).